# Is JodaTime parsing this datetime incorrectly?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, date-parsing

Is Joda parsing this ISO 8601 datetime string incorrectly?

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM ee kk:mm:ss z y").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).withLocale(Locale.US);    
DateTimeFormatter dtf = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
dt = dtf.parseDateTime("2015-04-01T11:40:59Z");
System.out.println(f.print(dt));
```

This outputs Wed Apr **03** 11:40:59 UTC 2015 but notice the input string specified April **01**

Comment: `ee` is the day of the week, were you expected `dd` which mean day of the month? http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e` is the day of the **week**. You're looking for `d`, which is the day of the **month**:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z y").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).withLocale(Locale.US);
```